# Is it possible to Mock the Platform APIs in eclipse to do Junit test?

Tags: java, eclipse, junit, mockito, platform

I am developing eclipse plugin and i need to do some test for it.
I want to spy eclipse runtime Platform API in my test class.
The scenario mentioned in my example to understand easily.

```
Class MyClass{
private boolean foo(){
  if (Platform.inDebugMode())
    {
    return  false;
    }
    else{
     return true;
   }
 }
}

Now I need to test  foo() method completly
 class MyClassTest{
MyClass myClass = new MyClass();

@Test
public void testFoo(){
assertTrue(myClass.foo()); 
}

@Test
public void testFooWithDebugMode(){
Mockito.doReturn(true).when(Platform).inDebugMode(); // Is this possible to mock this?
assertFalse(myClass.foo()); ​
}
}
```

Comment: what is the _actual_ question? do you know about `Mockito::mockStatic`?

Comment: Not much, but my question is that I need to mock the static method without using powermockito

Comment: have you read the comment above? How about reading about `mockStatic`?

Answer (score 0):

yes its possible to mock the platform API into eclipse to do Junit test
But before that user have to install following plugins.

1. org.eclipse.core.runtime
2. org.eclipse.ui
3. org.eclipse.ui.forms

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything neither about the eclipse platform nor about eclipse plugin development, however, instead of dealing with Statics, you can consider the following:

```
interface MyPlatformAdapter {
   boolean isInDebugMode();
}

class MyPlatformAdapaterImpl implements MyPlatformAdapter {
   public boolean isInDebugMode() {
     return Platform.inDebugMode();
   } 
}
```

Now your code becomes simple and unit testable:

```
Class MyClass{
  private final MyPlatformAdapter platform;

  public MyClass(MyPlatformAdapter platform) {
    this.platform = platform;
  }
  public boolean foo() {
     if (platform.isInDebugMode())
    {
    return  false;
    }
    else{
     return true;
   }
 }
}
```

And the test is trivial - no need for tools like PowerMockito that you're trying to avoid or mockito's static methods mocking facility.

Assuming you use this "Platform" which is full of static methods like this from many classes this approach can ease the tests and in general to make your code better. I kind of agree that the fewer places are using Platform in your project the more this looks like overkill, but still its a viable approach IMO.